# Is it possible to redefine the last nested layout instead of the first one?

Tags: nuxt.js

This is the test repository: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-dps2dp

As you can see on the `Level 2 / v2` page the `default` layout will be replaced, but I'm looking for a way to replace the `level-two` layout.

So layouts `default -> level-two` replaced as `level-two-alternative -> level-two` using `definePageMeta` inside the last page.

But I'm looking for a way to replace `default -> level-two` with `default -> level-two-alternative` instead.

Is it possible to use built-in Nuxt's stuff like `definePageMeta` or so?

---

In case the example link is dead, this is a simplified code:

**Root.vue**

```js
<template>
  <NuxtLayout name="one">
    <slot />
  </NuxtLayout>
</template>
```

**Child.vue**

```js
<template>
  <Root>
    <NuxtLayout name="two">
      <slot />
    </NuxtLayout>
  </Root>
</template>
```

**SubChild.vue**

```js
<template>
  <Child>
    Woof
  </Child>
</template>

<script>
  definePageMeta({
    layout: 'three' // <- it will replace layout "one" instead of "two"
  });
</script>
```